# styling using jquery based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML CODE, I have given background color red to #list . if the number of li is more than 5, i want to change the background to blue. please assist

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var len= $("#list li").size();
      if(len>5){
      // i need the code to style the #list here if number of li is more than 5, say background to blue
}
  });
  </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <ul id="list" style="background:red; width:300px;height:300px;">
<li>Image 1</li>
<li>Image 2</li>
    <li>Image 3</li>
<li>Image 4</li>
    <li>Image 5</li>
<li>Image 6</li>
    <li>Image 7</li>
<li>Image 8</li>
    <li>Image 9</li>
<li>Image 10</li>
  </ul>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Try: `$('#list').css('backgroundColor', 'blue');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `.length` instead of `size()`.

```
var len= $("#list li").length;
if(len>5){
    $("#list").css("background-color","blue"); //use .css() to change the background color
}
```

Comment: That worked. thank you. if i want to add more style properties, i seperate each by semi colon?

Comment: .css({ "color" : "blue", "width" : "200px" })  for multiple css properties

Answer (score 1):

Use [css method](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
if(len>5){
    $("#list").css("background-color","blue");
}
```

As per your comment you can use multiple css properties and values wrapping in medial braces `{}` like this:

```
if(len>5){
        $("#list").css({"background-color":"blue","color":"white"});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code

```
<ul id="list" style="background:red; width:300px;height:300px;">
<li>Image 1</li>
<li>Image 2</li>
    <li>Image 3</li>
<li>Image 4</li>
    <li>Image 5</li>
<li>Image 6</li>
    <li>Image 7</li>
<li>Image 8</li>
    <li>Image 9</li>
<li>Image 10</li>
  </ul>

var len= $("#list li").length;
      if(len>5){
      $("#list").css("background-color","blue");

}
```

[JsFriddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/w8tgB/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#list").css("background-color","red");
      if($("#list li").length>5){
        $("#list").css("background-color","blue");
      }
  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var len= $("#list li").length;
if(len>5)
     $("#list").addClass('blue').removeClass('red');   
else
     $("#list").addClass('red').removeClass('blue');
```

and your blue class in css is

```
.blue
{
    background-color : blue
 }
.red
{
   background-color : red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/FKvY4/)

```
($("#list li").length > 5) ? $("#list").css("background","blue"):$("#list").css("background","red")
```